# MongoDB running errors

Tags: mongodb

Can someone lend me a hand with a first time user's install issues?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am running this off of Virtualbox.

**1) I run 'mongod' and I get the following:**

`ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
, terminating`

**2) Where do I go to set this? I look into /etc/mongod.conf and see the following line: (how should I change this?)**

`dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb`

**3) When I attempt to run 'mongo' I get the following:**

`2015-01-19T01:02:38.625-0700 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused`

`2015-01-19T01:02:38.625-0700 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146`

`exception: connect failed`

**4) Also, I am not running on 127.0.0.1 so do I also change/set this from the mongod.conf file or set this elsewhere?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12401224/3664966?) ?

another thing that could help is to run mongod with the --dbpath parameter:

```
mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

But first make sure that this is your db directory.

Comment: How do put this in my db directory? Can you step me through it? I run the command (you suggested) and get this `Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating` my permissions on the mongod.lock are `rwx-xr-x`

Comment: One solution might be to run the command with sudo rights.
but be aware: this can cause a problem, where you can only start it with sudo rights afterwards. Therfore it will never start at boot.
You can also try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15982017/3664966 more sophisticated but maybe better solution.

Comment: Question, where do I make /data/db at? The root or some other folder?

Comment: Wherever you want to have your db location

Comment: I see, do you have any idea where I can change the IP for questions 3 and 4?

Comment: Try this:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--bind_ip
hope it helps